# How do I permanently run apps in the cloud?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cloud

I have been looking all over the internet for a way to run web browsers on the cloud(specifically Chrome and Firefox) while I am away. The solutions I found online allows me run these apps but do not allow me keep it running even after shutting off my PC.

I need help on any cloud service(s) that allows these features and is relatively cheap or free to setup, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a VPS and install you favorite operating system with your browser... and you can run your browsers 24/7 with your pc off!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a bit more research based on your response and found a video on Youtube that described how to use amazon web services set up a VPS, and it is free to set up!!. Here is the link to the video for anyone who might need it in the future: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F31xQh7e51Q